# How do I extract overlapping character patterns with regex?

Tags: regular-expression

Is it possible to create a regular expression that would match overlapping character patterns?

For example, I'd like to match **abc**, **bcd**, **cde** and **def** from string **abcdef**.

If it is not possible, can you do the same with the two other stone age tools; sed and awk?

Comment: What’s the rule that extracts those results? Three letters? “Every 3-letter substring”?

Comment: Your title say **extract**, that is something a regex could not do, only some tools by replacing what was matched with something else. As such you are actually asking for a tool to perform the extraction.

Comment: The body of your question say **match**. Any regex will `match` any three characters. A simple `...` (3 dots) will match any of the 3 letters (but it will **not extract**). Could you explain better what is it that you want?

Comment: Jeff, any pattern including evry three letter substring.

Comment: Isaac, I guess I have always mixed up the regex and the way I mostly use it in vi to do search and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is to **repeatly extract 3 characters**, then:

In old sed:

```
$ sed ':1;h;s/\(...\).*/\1/p;g;s/.//;t1;d'  <<<$'abcdef\n1234567\n'
abc
bcd
cde
def
123
234
345
456
567
```

In old awk:

```
$ awk '{a=$0;for(i=1;i<length(a)-1;i++){print substr(a,i,3)}}' <<<$'abcdef\n1234567'
abc
bcd
cde
def
123
234
345
456
567
```